# Org Chart not working for People pIcker

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

Reference of plugin
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Customizable-Organisational-Chart-Plugin-With-jQuery-OrgChart/

I am using List schema as TeamMember(PeoplePicker),FunctionalManager(PeoplePicker),Department(SingleLinetext)
and trying below code to create org chart in SharePoint

But it only create first node not the rest but however if create FunctionalManager as Lookup column it work but the requirement  have with People picker can any one help where making mistake

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css'/> 
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Employee (ID,Name,Manager,Designation) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Name= Name;
    this.Manager = Manager;
    this.Designation = Designation;
}
function GetOrgJSON(employeeList,manager){
    var note = '';
    var employeeProcessed=[];
    for(var i=0;i<employeeList.length;i++){
        var objEmp = employeeList[i];      
        if(objEmp.Manager == manager && employeeProcessed.indexOf(objEmp.Name) < 0 ){
            note += '{"name":"'+objEmp.Name+'",';
            note += '"title":"'+objEmp.Designation+'"';
            employeeProcessed.push(objEmp.Name);
            var empUl = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,objEmp.ID);
            if(empUl !=""){
                note +=',"children": [' + empUl + ']';
            }
            note +='},';
        }       
    } 
    return note;
}
(function($){
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXX/_api/web/lists(guid'627bae98-f8f4-437d-91c5-14ef8e10eef3')/items?$select=ID,TeamMember/ID,TeamMember/Title,FunctionalManager/ID,FunctionalManager/Title,Department&$expand=TeamMember/Id,FunctionalManager/Id",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                var employeeList = [];
                $.each(data.d.results,function(i,employee){
                    var title = employee.TeamMember.Title;
                    var ID = employee.ID;
                    var manager = employee.FunctionalManager.ID!= undefined ? employee.FunctionalManager.ID:"0";
                    var designation=employee.Department;
                    var objEmp = new Employee(ID,title ,manager,designation);
                    employeeList.push(objEmp);
                });
                var datascource = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,"0").replace(/},]/g,"}]");
                datascource=datascource.slice(0, datascource.length-1);
                
                $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                  'data' : JSON.parse(datascource),
                  'nodeContent': 'title'
                }); 
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });  
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: What's the error while using person or group column?

Comment: It does not give error but unable to compare  it create child node when debugging

Comment: Both lookup & person or group columns have similar properties like `.ID` & `.Title`. So, it should have worked for you.

Comment: yes tried but it only show top node

Comment: Try changing line `var manager = employee.FunctionalManager.ID!= undefined ? employee.FunctionalManager.ID:"0";` to `var manager = employee.FunctionalManager.ID ? employee.FunctionalManager.ID : "0";` in case of person or group and see if it works.

Comment: it does not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am able to resolve my code its small change in code below is the updated code

below is the change

```
var ID = employee.TeamMember.ID;
```

updated code

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css'/> 
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Employee (ID,Name,Manager,Designation) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Name= Name;
    this.Manager = Manager;
    this.Designation = Designation;
}
function GetOrgJSON(employeeList,manager){
    var note = '';
    var employeeProcessed=[];
    for(var i=0;i<employeeList.length;i++){
        var objEmp = employeeList[i];      
        if(objEmp.Manager == manager && employeeProcessed.indexOf(objEmp.Name) < 0 ){
            note += '{"name":"'+objEmp.Name+'",';
            note += '"title":"'+objEmp.Designation+'"';
            employeeProcessed.push(objEmp.Name);
            var empUl = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,objEmp.ID);
            if(empUl !=""){
                note +=',"children": [' + empUl + ']';
            }
            note +='},';
        }       
    } 
    return note;
}
(function($){
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXX/_api/web/lists(guid'627bae98-f8f4-437d-91c5-14ef8e10eef3')/items?$select=ID,TeamMember/ID,TeamMember/Title,FunctionalManager/ID,FunctionalManager/Title,Department&$expand=TeamMember/Id,FunctionalManager/Id",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                var employeeList = [];
                $.each(data.d.results,function(i,employee){
                    var title = employee.TeamMember.Title;
                    var ID = employee.TeamMember.ID;
                    var manager = employee.FunctionalManager.ID!= undefined ? employee.FunctionalManager.ID:"0";
                    var designation=employee.Department;
                    var objEmp = new Employee(ID,title ,manager,designation);
                    employeeList.push(objEmp);
                });
                var datascource = GetOrgJSON(employeeList,"0").replace(/},]/g,"}]");
                datascource=datascource.slice(0, datascource.length-1);
                
                $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                  'data' : JSON.parse(datascource),
                  'nodeContent': 'title'
                }); 
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });  
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```